# Mysql convert FullText Search Query to REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex, full-text-search

I'm working to implement functionality to search records  from database in which provided keywords are exists. So I chose FUll Text indexing. But it feels there are some of the drawbacks of this query. like we can't find two characters word. So I'm trying to use REGEX in mysql.

Here is my SQL query with FULLTEXT Query.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE MATCH (field_name) AGAINST ('+what +that' IN boolean MODE)
```

And I tried to convert this query to REGEX

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE REGEXP '[[:<:]]what that[[:>:]]'
```

But this query is not working. Can anyone suggest me what I'm doing wrong in this query?

Comment: in your first example you have `"`in match whereas in your regex you don't have `"`

Comment: @CodeManiac Please check my updated question

Comment: can you create a [`snippet here`](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your question

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: @CodeManiac here is the snippet `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418cc3/5`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mysql version is 5.6+

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh something like [`this`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418cc3/24) can be done, or `[[:<:]]earth .* flat[[:>:]]` like this

Comment: The equivalent of that FT query is (approximately) `WHERE txt REGEXP '[[:<:]]what[[:>:]]' AND WHERE txt REGEXP '[[:<:]]that[[:>:]]'`